# Is there a way to control who can access a DNS server?

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, security, access-control-list

Besides IP whitelisting at a firewall level, is there a possible way to only allow specific authorized people to contact and use a DNS server sitting on a public IP?

If I understand the OSI model correctly, you can't use MAC addresses if I remember right.

Places like OpenDNS have a subscription based model so I assume that there is a possible way you can control who can access your DNS server?

Goal:
The idea is to setup DNS Server(s) for specific businesses/clients with custom records but also don't want to allow just anyone to be able to use the DNS server(s).

Comment: AFAIK, you have to login to OpenDNS and they then use the source IP of this login to permit the traffic in their DNS server implementation (i.e. not very different then firewall rules).

Comment: Could you add details around the use cases or scenerios you are wanting to implement the control?

Comment: What DNS server are you running?  Bind has the allow-query flag that limits access to zones and may be what you're looking for.

Comment: It will be helpful if you would add some details regarding DNS server which is currently running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't pin your clients to fixed IP addresses, I would suggest either:

- Have a look at dnscrypt, which allows only authenticated DNS requests
- Make your clients connect via VPN and regain control over the source IP addresses

Solutions which give you the current IP address of your client, like previous login or even port knocking, to punch holes in your boundaries (eg. firewall) are not as secure.

Alas, all those solutions require some action on your client's side. I don't think you get that fixed fully transparently.

Answer (score 1):

A very common nameserver, 'bind' contains supports for ACLs and limiting queries and DNS recursion with these ACLs. In short, using bind you can configure who can access and perform certain types of lookups based on single IPs and IP ranges, block them completely and open them up completely.

See here for more info: https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/s1-bind-namedconf.html

To answer your question, yes it is possible to do this without a firewall, but using a firewall and using ACLs aren't exactly the same and you might want to use a firewall (blocking malicious activity) for one reason and ACLs for another (setting up a recursive server only rather than an authoritative DNS server).